# If we don't know that two sets are independent but there intersection is equal to their multiplication, can we say they are independent?

Tags: probability, independence

Lets say $P(A) = 0.2$ and $P(B) = 0.3$, and we know that $$ P(A \cap B ) = 0.06 $$
Does this mean the events are independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Definition), two events $A$ and $B$ are independent if and only if $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.

But $0.2\times 0.3\ne 0.6$ in your example. [Notes: the question was edited later.] If you have instead
$$
P(A)=0.2,\quad P(B)=0.3,\quad P(A\cap B)=0.06
$$
then you can conclude that $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the question body to match the title, since I was pretty sure that Thomas had just made an arithmetic error.

Comment: @Joe: thanks for the notification.

Comment: @Joe I agree with the edit since $\Pr(A\cap B)$ can't be greater than $\Pr(A)$.  It is impossible for $\Pr(A\cap B)=0.6>0.2=\Pr(A)$ by monotonicity

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ and $B$ two events, so the events are independent if and only if any of the three conditions is met :

1. $\mathbb{P}[A|B]=\mathbb{P}[A]$.
2. $ \mathbb{P}[B|A]=\mathbb{P}[B]$.
3. $\mathbb{P}[A\cap B]=\mathbb{P}[A]\cdot \mathbb{P}[B]$.

Therefore, you need only verify in this case the condition number $3$.

Comment: The way you write this makes it sound like you are saying that you need to check all three of the conditions.  In reality, all three are equivalent.  You only need to check one of the conditions to know the truth of all the conditions and it doesn't matter which of them you checked.

Comment: The three conditions are equivalent though, so you only need to verify any one of them. $P(A|B)P(B)=P(A)P(B|A)$ by definition of conditional probability and (3) implies both (1) and (2) and any one of (1),(2) implies (3)

Comment: Yes, you're right. I edited my post.